# How to convert linq results to HashSet or HashedSet

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a property on a class that is an ISet.  I'm trying to get the results of a linq query into that property, but can't figure out how to do so.

Basically, looking for the last part of this:

```
ISet<T> foo = new HashedSet<T>();
foo = (from x in bar.Items select x).SOMETHING;
```

Could also do this:

```
HashSet<T> foo = new HashSet<T>();
foo = (from x in bar.Items select x).SOMETHING;
```

Comment: I think you should leave out the `HashedSet`-part. It is just confusing since `C#` and `LINQ` do not have anything called `HashedSet`.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Edit (2023): There is now an `ToHashSet` extension method - see [Douglas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220435/221166) below.

*Original Answer*:

I don't *think* there's anything built in which does this... but it's really easy to write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
    }
}
```

Note that you really do want an extension method (or at least a generic method of some form) here, because you may not be able to express the type of `T` explicitly:

```
var query = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            select new { i, j = i + 1 };
var resultSet = query.ToHashSet();
```

You can't do that with an explicit call to the `HashSet<T>` constructor. We're relying on type inference for generic methods to do it for us.

Now you *could* choose to name it `ToSet` and return `ISet<T>` - but I'd stick with `ToHashSet` and the concrete type. This is consistent with the standard LINQ operators (`ToDictionary`, `ToList`) and allows for future expansion (e.g. `ToSortedSet`). You may also want to provide an overload specifying the comparison to use.

Comment: Good point on anonymous types. However, do anonymous types have useful overrides of `GetHashCode` and `Equals`? If not, they're not going to be much good in a HashSet...

Comment: @Joel: Yes, they do. Otherwise all kinds of things would fail. Admittedly they only use the default equality comparers for the component types, but that's usually good enough.

Comment: Good to know. In that case, yes, the extension method would be more generally useful than using the constructor directly.

Comment: @Jon: out of interest, are there any little tricks that you can use to force it to use a different equality comparer than the default?

Comment: @DoctaJonez: For anonymous types? No. But you can create a HashSet with a custom equality comparer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - do you know if there's any reason why this isn't supplied in the standard LINQ operators alongside ToDictionary and ToList? I've heard that there are often good reasons why such things are omitted, similar to the missing IEnumerable<T>.ForEach method

Comment: @StephenHolt: I agree with the resistance to `ForEach`, but `ToHashSet` makes a lot more sense - I don't know of any reason not to do `ToHashSet` other than the normal "doesn't meet the usefulness bar" (which I'd disagree with, but...)

Comment: @Dan: Does what, exactly?

Comment: @JonSkeet return new HashSet<T>(source);

Comment: @Dan: Then lose performance versus what? It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet. Let me try to be more specific: Let's suppose that we that we have an IQueryable from an Entity (Entity Framework) and I want to convert it to HashSet (because looks like more "faster" and "cheaper"). I would like to know if this conversion take more processing and does lose performance because the conversion.

Comment: @Dan: They're very different. Constructing the set will eliminate duplicates, for one thing.

Comment: Nice, I would add an `IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null` argument.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Since this is the top-rated answer here, you might want to edit in a remark pointing to Douglas's answer and the now-existing ToHashSet<>() framework method.

Comment: @TorbenKlein: You can do so if you want; I don't go over all my answers every year to check whether they're still up-to-date.

Comment: Oh, I can edit answers ... nice :-)
I'm aware that no sane persons reviews their answers regularly, thats why I commented ;-)

Answer (score 89):

Just pass your IEnumerable into the constructor for HashSet.

```
HashSet<T> foo = new HashSet<T>(from x in bar.Items select x);
```

Comment: How are you going to cope with a projection which results in an anonymous type?

Comment: @Jon, I'd assume that's YAGNI until confirmed otherwise.

Comment: Clearly I'm not. Fortunately, in this particular example, I don't need to.

Comment: @Jon the type is specified by OP (the first line wouldn't compiler otherwise) so in this case I have to agree it's YAGNI for now

Comment: @Rune FS: In this case, I suspect the sample code isn't realistic. It's pretty rare to have a type parameter T but know that each item of `bar.Items` is going to be `T`. Given how easy it is to make this general purpose, and how frequently anonymous types come up in LINQ, I think it's worth taking the extra step.

Comment: @Jon agreed and that's the reason why got +1. It might not be necessary in this particular case but as a general example (and thus good for all googlers) the approach of wrapping it in a generic method serves as a good example

Answer (score 51):

This functionality has been added as an extension method on `IEnumerable<TSource>` to [.NET Framework 4.7.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/dotnet472-changes.md#bcl) and [.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netcore-2.0). It is consequently also available on [.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=net-5.0) and later.

- [`ToHashSet<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt829068(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`ToHashSet<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt829062(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also included with [netcore 2.0 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netcore-3.0)

Answer (score 20):

As @Joel stated, you can just pass your enumerable in.  If you want to do an extension method, you can do:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(items);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension method build in the .NET framework and in .NET core for converting an `IEnumerable` to a `HashSet`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=ToHashSet

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<TSource> ToHashSet<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

It appears that I cannot use it in .NET standard libraries yet (at the time of writing). So then I use this extension method:

```
    [Obsolete("In the .NET framework and in NET core this method is available, " +
              "however can't use it in .NET standard yet. When it's added, please remove this method")]
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) => new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty simple :)

```
var foo = new HashSet<T>(from x in bar.Items select x);
```

and yes T is the type specified by OP :)

Comment: That doesn't specify a type argument.

Comment: Lol that has got to be the harshest down vote of the day:). To me there's exactly the same info now. Beats me why the type inference system isn't already inferring that type anyways :)

Comment: Undone now... but it's actually pretty significant precisely *because* you don't get type inference. See my answer.

Comment: I can't remember seeing it on Eric's blog why inference on constructors is not a part of the spec's do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

If you need just readonly access to the set and the source is a parameter to your method, then I would go with

```
public static ISet<T> EnsureSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    ISet<T> result = source as ISet<T>;
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

The reason is, that the users may call your method with the `ISet` already so you do not need to create the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Jon's answer is perfect. The only caveat is that, using NHibernate's HashedSet, I need to convert the results to a collection. Is there an optimal way to do this?

```
ISet<string> bla = new HashedSet<string>((from b in strings select b).ToArray());
```

or

```
ISet<string> bla = new HashedSet<string>((from b in strings select b).ToList());
```

Or am I missing something else?

---

Edit: This is what I ended up doing:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}

public static HashedSet<T> ToHashedSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashedSet<T>(source.ToHashSet());
}
```

Comment: `ToList` is generally more efficient than `ToArray`. Does it just need to implement `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: Correct.  I ended up going with your method, then using that to do the ToHashedSet (see edit on original question).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the simple conversion of IEnumerable to a HashSet, it is often convenient to convert a property of another object into a HashSet. You could write this as:

```
var set = myObject.Select(o => o.Name).ToHashSet();
```

but, my preference would be to use selectors:

```
var set = myObject.ToHashSet(o => o.Name);
```

They do the same thing, and the the second is obviously shorter, but I find the idiom fits my brains better (I think of it as being like ToDictionary).

Here's the extension method to use, with support for custom comparers as a bonus.

```
public static HashSet<TKey> ToHashSet<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    return new HashSet<TKey>(source.Select(selector), comparer);
}
```