# Convert an array to a HashSet<T> in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How do I convert an array to a hash set ?

```
string[]  BlockedList = BlockList.Split(new char[] { ';' },     
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I need to convert this list to a `hashset`.

Comment: What kind of list/array is this? What does it contain?

Comment: Calling it BlockList is *very* misleading.  I'd suggest BlockNames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert linq results to HashSet or HashedSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471899/how-to-convert-linq-results-to-hashset-or-hashedset)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You do not specify what type `BlockedList` is, so I will assume it is something that derives from `IList` (if meant to say `String` where you wrote `BlockList` then it would be a string array which derives from `IList`).

`HashSet` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable`, so you need merely pass the list into this constructor, as `IList` derives from `IEnumerable`.

```
var set = new HashSet(BlockedList);
```

Comment: Calling `Split` on this mystery type, with a parameter of char array and `StringSplitOptions` kinda indicates that BlockedList is a string.

Comment: as much as I hate making assumptions, looking at the `.Split` method and `StringSplitOptions`, I would have to assume `String` array.

Answer (score 21):

I'm assuming BlockList is a string (hence the call to Split) which returns a string array.

Just pass the array (which implements IEnumerable) to the [constructor of the HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx):

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(BlockedList);
```

Answer (score 14):

#### Update 2017 - For .Net Framework 4.7.1+ and .Net Core 2.0+

There is now a built-in [`ToHashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```cs
var hashSet = BlockedList.ToHashSet();
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is an extension method that will generate a HashSet from any IEnumerable:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

To use it with your example above:

```
var hashSet = BlockedList.ToHashSet();
```

Answer (score 2):

Missed new keyword on extension example....

```
  public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To take one step further, the following one-liner demonstrates how you can convert a *literal* string array to a HashSet, so that you do NOT have to define an intermediate variable `SomethingList`.

```
var directions = new HashSet<string>(new [] {"east", "west", "north", "south"});
```

Comment: Although it did not answer the original question, it helped me!

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
List<int> a1 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
List<int> b1 = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
List<int> a2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> b2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> a3 = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
List<int> b3 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

List<int> a4 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> b4 = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
List<int> a5 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
List<int> b5 = new List<int> { };
List<int> a6 = new List<int> { };
List<int> b6 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
List<int> a7 = new List<int> { };
List<int> b7 = new List<int> { };

HashSet<int> first = new HashSet<int>(a1);
HashSet<int> second = new HashSet<int>(b1);
first.Overlaps(second);

first = new HashSet<int>(a2);
second = new HashSet<int>(b2);
first.Overlaps(second);

first = new HashSet<int>(a3);
second = new HashSet<int>(b3);
first.Overlaps(second);

first = new HashSet<int>(a4);
second = new HashSet<int>(b4);
first.Overlaps(second);

first = new HashSet<int>(a5);
second = new HashSet<int>(b5);
first.Overlaps(second);

first = new HashSet<int>(a6);
second = new HashSet<int>(b6);
first.Overlaps(second);

first = new HashSet<int>(a7);
second = new HashSet<int>(b7);
first.SetEquals(second);
```

Comment: he said an array not a list