# Convert Classes to EF Classes using Property Names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a load of classes similar to those shown below. These classes are all in the namespace `API_Classes`; they have some very similar counterparts in another namespace called `Database_Classes` (again, see below).

API_Classes

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    //....lots of other properties, some lists, some single values
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubRecipe> SubRecipes { get; set; }
    //....lots of other properties, some lists, some single values
}
```

Database_Classes

```
public partial class Recipe
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Recipe()
    {
        this.Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
        this.SubRecipes = new HashSet<SubRecipe>)();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    // and more properties, matching the AP_Class that is called the same thing
}

public partial class Ingredient
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Ingredient()
    {
        this.SubRecipes = new HashSet<SubRecipe>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubRecipe> SubRecipes { get; set; }
    // and more properties, matching the AP_Class that is called the same thing
}
```

I need to take the extant API Classes and use them to initialize Database Classes. All the classes have the same names as their counterparts and the properties too. The difference is that the Database classes were created by Entity Framework 6 and contain virtual HashSets instead of lists. Is there some sort of generalized way to initialize a set of Database_Class classes from the "matching" API_Classes without writing out every property and every class, making them all match, when the class and property names exist in both sets of classes.

I have spent some time Googling around because I think there should be a way using reflection, but to be honest I'm struggling to find the syntax I need to search for the problem I am seeing. On top of that there is the problem of converting the Lists to HashSets. I see that this conversion shouldn't be a problem ([Convert an array to a HashSet<T> in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156626/convert-an-array-to-a-hashsett-in-net)), but it seems to me it might get in the way of a totally straightforward class creation (although I know the values in the lists will always be unique).

Any pointers or examples would be really helpful to me - I have about 80 classes to go through at the moment and each has a lot of properties; I would love to avoid writing out the whole conversion from one set of classes to another!

Comment: You do not need reflection.  Just make sure the full pathname is the same in all classes using the classes.  The full pathname include the namespace(s) and the parent/child class name(s).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand - the class names match, but not the namespaces; do you mean I should put all the classes into one namespace or...? I'm sorry, I think I am missing something

Comment: If you are using the same class definition from two namespaces only have the class in one namespace and reference from second namespace using full path.  You should not have two copies of the same class.

Comment: I'm sorry I feel like a real idiot here, but I don't know what you mean. The class definitions do not exactly match and one of each pair is generated from EF6, so I don't want to edit it. I am presented with those and the API import returns other classes, again with which I am presented. I would like to convert the API classes into Database Classes based on their definitions, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: The you need a base class with separate inherited classes so you can easily cast one into the other.

Comment: You can try using automapper from https://automapper.org/, then with your IMapper you do `IMapper#Map<Ingredient, IngredientDto>(ingredient);` to map the values over to the dto(api) class.

Comment: automapper looks like exactly the tool I need - I imagine there will be a bit of work involved in doing the list to HashSet conversion, but even without that, this will take a huge amount of the work away. I would give this the answer tick if you put it as an answer.