# Are these the simplest ways to apply several different actions to a list of strings using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

In this case, the source of the text is from a winforms textbox. I'm asking this primarily to learn more about LINQ and maybe to demonstrate its strength (easier to read than loops, in my opinion). This program had several requirements; the function had to get the text from the textbox, split it into its separate lines, remove empty and/or duplicate lines, and trim the lines.

Are these the only ways to do this? Are there other methods for this in C# (apart from looping through the list of lines and adding items that meet the criteria to a new list, array, etc.)?

1:

```
List<String> listOne = textBoxWords.Text
                                   .Split(new char [] { '\r', '\n' })
                                   .Select(s1 => s1.Trim())
                                   .Where(s2 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList();
```

2:

```
List<String> listTwo = textBoxWords.Text
                                   .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                   .Select(s1 => s1.Trim())
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList();
```

UPDATE: This code was suggested, but only works if the strings don't need to be trimmed.

3:

```
List<String> listThree = textBoxWords.Text
                                     .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' },
                                     .Where(s1 => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s1))
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .ToList();
```

I know it's a) fairly specific, and b) could probably be implemented easier using a DataGrid, but the code I'm maintaining uses textboxes and I didn't immediately want to rewrite them.

Comment: Those all look like perfectly sensible ways to do what you want.

Comment: @ThomSmith I added the last one to demonstrate another similar but not suitable version (for the purposes of this program) and to show a bit more of the power of simple LINQ. Coming from a Python background (e.g. with list comprehensions) these are quite nice features.

Comment: You could use a Hashset instead which will be slightly less verbose.

Comment: A HashSet would be *more* verbose. Distinct is your hashset replacement, and it is shorter and its purpose is clearly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var setOne = new HashSet<string>(textBoxWords.Text
                               .Split(new char [] { '\r', '\n' })
                               .Select(s1 => s1.Trim())
                               .Where(s2 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s2)));
```

It's not exactly the same as what you have since the result is a HashSet, but based on your scenario it looks like that may be the better data structure for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was just about to comment and ask for a code snippet, since I was thinking of using the accepted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3471927/869912) to write a custom extension method (albeit an extremely simple one) that would implement `ToHashedSet`.

Comment: Isn't that code missing a type declaration? `var setOne = new HashSet<String>(...)` instead of `var setOne = new HashSet(...)`? Actually yes, my compiler throws an error if I don't include a type declaration.

Comment: What is the advantage of this method? Is is more verbose and the intention of this code is less obvious. It is about equal on efficiency.

Comment: It should be noted that `HashSet` doesn't necessarily enumerate the elements in the same order you put them in (i.e. the file's lines will be jumbled randomly).  Judging from what the asker said, this might be a problem.  His examples with `List<>` and `Distinct` make more sense, from what I can tell.

Comment: In this case, the elements are sorted before display, so it isn't a problem if they get out of order. I could use SortedSet if I wanted, but List seems to work fine here (especially because it never grows past 100 or so elements)

Comment: Agreed with comments but op was specifically asking for *other* ways to do this.  It will also depend on what he wants to do next: If, for example, he wants to add elements after constructing the set, HashSet may be the more appropriate result.

Comment: @IanMercer Even if it's not perfect for my situation in question, I definitely appreciate new ideas that I can use elsewhere, which is why I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are already fairly simple. One alternative would be:

```
(from s in textBoxWords.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
select s.Trim()).Distinct();
```