# Optimize IEnumerable to HashSet conversion in LINQ

Tags: performance, linq, ienumerable, hashset

```
public HashSet<Student> GetStudents(int studentId)
{
    IEnumerable<Student> studentTypes = this.studentTypes .Where(x => (x.studentID== studentId));
    if (studentTypes .FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {

        //return new HashSet<Student>(studentTypes);
        return studentTypes.ToHashSet();
    }
    else
    {
        return new HashSet<Student>();
    }
}

public static class LinqUtilities
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();

        foreach (var en in enumerable)
        {
            hashSet.Add(en);
        }

        return hashSet;
    }
}
```

This function is called alot of times say 1000 times and there are 5000 students in the result set.
How can I optimize this function ...I know that the conversion from `IEnumerable` to `HashSet` is causing a lot of overheads.
`ToHashSet` is my extension method.
This function is to slow and eating a lot of time.

Comment: added toHashSet ...the to hashset is code from the internet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you don't need to enumerate the hashset values in your utilities function
you could improve the efficient by using nice static extension class written by @Jon

[Converting linq result to hashset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471899/how-to-convert-linq-results-to-hashset-or-hashedset)

and i think you don't need to check on the FirstOrDefault since the extension will handle the new student object given T 
so you could change to more clean and tidy way.

```
IEnumerable<Student> studentTypes = this.studentTypes.Where(x => (x.studentID== studentId));
return studentTypes.toHashSet();
```

The other option is you can pass you IEnumerable into your constructor for HashSet
like

```
HashSet<Student> studentTypes = new HashSet<Student>(this.studentTypes.Where(x => (x.studentID== studentId)));
```

so you only have one line of code in your GetStudents function

Comment: But would this increase performance..??beacuse  doing new hashset for large values is decreasing the performance

Comment: Hashset(T) it self provides high performance set operation. I'm not sure what you refer on performance but certainly the optimization is to avoid duplicate call of the enumeration for your conversion in LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

Don't run the query twice per call.

```
 //sets up a deferred query.  This query will be "executed" when enumerated.
IEnumerable<Student> studentTypes = this.studentTypes
  .Where(x => (x.studentID== studentId));

 //enumeration #1 (stops on first hit)
if (studentTypes .FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
   //enumeration #2
   return studentTypes.ToHashSet();
```

Your condition is unnecessary:

```
 //sets up a deferred query.  This query will be "executed" when enumerated.
IEnumerable<Student> studentTypes = this.studentTypes
  .Where(x => (x.studentID== studentId));

 //enumeration #1
 return studentTypes.ToHashSet();
```

---

> I know that the conversion from Ienumerable to Hasset is causing a lot
>   of overheads

That's bull.  You've measured nothing and are misleading yourself to optimize the wrong part of the code.

Comment: Your last line is entirely true. The OP is making arbitrary assumptions.