# Add, Update, Remove between collections using Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Here is my scenario.  I am using WPF and making use of two way binding to show a collection objects received from a service call every 60 seconds.  On the first call I create a collection of objects that will be displayed from the  collection of service objects.  On subsequent calls I need to compare the service collection to the existing collection and then do one of three things:

1. If the Item exists in both collections then update ALL of the values for the object in the Display collection with the values from the object in the service collection.
2. If the item Exists in the Service Collection and not the Display Collection then add it to the Display Collection.
3. If the Item exists in the Display collection and not the Service Collection then remove it from the Display collection.

I am looking for the best way to do this.

**Adding & Removing**
Is it smarter to do a Left Join here and return everything essentially unique to one side of the other and then add or remove that as appropriate?

Should I attempt to do a Union since Linq is supposed to merge the two and ignore the duplicates?
If so how does it decide uniqueness?  Is it evaluating all the properties?  Can I specify which collection to keep from and which to discard in merging?

Should I use Except to create a list of differences and somehow use that?

Should I create a new list to add and remove using Where / Not In logic?

**Updating**
Since the collections aren't dictionaries what is the best way to do the comparison:

```
list1.ForEach(x => list2[x.Id].SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty);
```

Is there some way of copying ALL the property values other than specifying each one of them similar to above?  Can I perform some kind of shallow copy within Linq Without replacing the actual object that is there?

I don't want to just clear my list and re-add everything each time because the object is bound in the display and I have logic in the properties that is tracking deviations as values change.

Comment: Your so-called comparison example is an assignment, not a comparison.  Did you mean to write "assignment"?

Comment: In net you are replacing the Display with the Service.  Why not just empty the Display and fill it with the Service?

Comment: Do you add the objects by, for example, `list1.Add(list2[index]);`?  If so, there is no need to update property values; the objects are identical.  The same object is an element in both lists.  If the other list contains new non-identical objects after subsequent calls, then you should just set `list1[targetIndex] = list2[sourceIndex]` (after determining the appropriate target index, of course).

Comment: @phoog My apologies I was just trying to show that if it was a dictionary I could use the [key] to determine which object to update.

Comment: @phoog I don't think I can just change the pointer like that using the list index in this case for two reasons.  The item in that list is two-way bound to a grid in WPF.  By doing this I'm just swapping references and not updating the actual data.  I need the property to change because there is logic to track Deviations.

Comment: If you actually need to copy data from one property to the other then you'll need to write that all out manually.  In the app I work on at work I am not intimately familiar with our code that handles this, but basically we are not continually polling our database so we are essentially only writing user updates to the db.  This can cause concurrency problems but our use case does not have multiple users editing the same objects at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the except and intersect methods to accomplish most of what you are looking to do.

However, depending on the size of your objects this can be very resource intensive.

I would recommend the following.

```
var listIDsA = collectionA.Select(s => s.Id).Distinct().ToList();

var listIDsB = collecitonB.Select(s => s.Id).Distinct().ToList();

var idsToRemove  = listIDsB.Select (s => !listIDsA.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();

var idsToUpdate = listIDsB.Select(s => listIDsA.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();

var idsToAdd = listIDsA.SelecT(s => !listIDsB.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();
```

Then using the three new collections you can add/remove/update the apporpriate records.

You can also use a hashedset instead of IEnumerables for better performance. This will require you to create an extension class to add that functionality. Here is a good explanation of how to do that (it's not complicated).

[How to convert linq results to HashSet or HashedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471899/how-to-convert-linq-results-to-hashset-or-hashedset)

If you do this, you will need to replace the .ToList() in the first two lines to .ToHasedSet()

Comment: I'd recomment a `hashSetIdsA` and `B` rather than a `listIdsA` and `B` if you're going to be doing a lot of `Contains` checks.

Comment: @Rawling Thanks. I updated my response with that information.

Comment: Each of the lines with .Contains gives the error, "Unknown method 'Select(?)' of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.

Answer (score 1):

For your comparison you need to overwrite equals and get hashcode

[Object.GetHashCode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you can use List.Contains
[List.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you can use HashSet then you will get better performance

Code not tested

```
ListDisplay.Remove(x => !ListSerice.Contains(x));
Foreash(ListItem li in ListDisplay)
{
   ListItem lis =  ListSerice.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(li));
   if (lis == null) continue;
   // perform update
}
Foreach(ListItem li in ListSerice.Where(x => !ListDisplay.Contains(x))) ListDisplay.Add(li);
```

Comment: When performing the update is the only way to pretty much set each property 1 by 1?  Is there any sort of shallow copy that will update without replacing the object?

Comment: Just search SO for shallow copy.  Come on show some effort.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't just trying to slack off.  My question just came across wrong.  Shallow Copy or MemberwiseClone works by creating a New Instance of object.  It wouldn't actually transpose those values onto another existing object.  I was wondering if the ability existed within linq to copy all the properties on an object without individually specifying them and without replacing the object you want to update.  I suspect the answer is No but I have been surprised before.

Comment: Not in LINQ that I know of.  I would just do it manually.  That would be more efficient than enumerating properties and some properties (e.g. the ID) you would not need to copy.