# Convert nested JSON to CSV

Tags: c#, json, csv

I am converting a nested JSON object with more than 10 levels to CSV file in C# .NET.

I have been using `JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ObjectA>(json)` or `XmlNode xml = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json)` to break down the object. With the objects I can further write into CSV file. However now the JSON object further expand. Most data that is not really in use so I would prefer a raw data dump.

Is that easier way I can just dump the data into csv format without declaring the structure?

Sample JSON

```
{
"F1":1,
"F2":2,
"F3":[
    {
        "E1":3,
        "E2":4
    },
    {
        "E1":5,
        "E2":6
    },  
    {
        "E1":7,
        "E2":8,
        "E3":[
            {
                "D1":9,
                "D2":10
            }
        ]
    },      
]
}
```

And my expected CSV output is

```
F1,F2,E1,E2,D1,D2
1,2
1,2,3,4
1,2,5,6
1,2,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: can you not convert that data into a datatable.. then from there convert to CSV

Comment: @MethodMan that's exactly what I did to handle the first few levels. After all I found it's too time consuming to put them into structure so I am checking if there's any automation.

Comment: where is the source of data coming from.. is it stored in a db ..?

Comment: @MethodMan It's from HttpContext, I've further made it into string.

Comment: You dont want `F3` in output ?

Comment: @ErrHunter no, the child element would be enough to represent F3

Comment: @ErrHunter i think he dont need ..he included F3 children

Comment: I have somewhat tried, Check here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/7MBHUc
Its not working, but i am able to traverse. Will update as next when possible.

Comment: @ErrHunter Looks like a closer solution. 1) Need to get rid of the node with child elements; and 2) more data type checks

Comment: @ydoow, Yes i know. But i am bit out, so can update after 8-10 hrs.

Comment: There is some inconsistency in your requirement.  You write a row for the root object, which has children; you do not write a row for the `"F3[2]"` object, which has children.  Is there a simple rule to tell when to write a row for an object that has children?

Answer (score 13):

There's an inconsistency in your request: you want a row to be generated for the root object, which has children, but you don't want a row to be generated for the `"F3[2]"` object, which also has children.  So it sounds like your rule is, "print a row for an object with at least one primitive-value property, as long as that object is either the root object or does not have descendant objects with at a least one primitive-value property".  That's a little tricky, but can be done with [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

```
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

        // Collect column titles: all property names whose values are of type JValue, distinct, in order of encountering them.
        var values = obj.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Value is JValue)
            .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
            .ToList();

        var columns = values.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

        // Filter JObjects that have child objects that have values.
        var parentsWithChildren = values.SelectMany(g => g).SelectMany(v => v.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Skip(1)).ToHashSet();

        // Collect all data rows: for every object, go through the column titles and get the value of that property in the closest ancestor or self that has a value of that name.
        var rows = obj
            .DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JObject>()
            .Where(o => o.PropertyValues().OfType<JValue>().Any())
            .Where(o => o == obj || !parentsWithChildren.Contains(o)) // Show a row for the root object + objects that have no children.
            .Select(o => columns.Select(c => o.AncestorsAndSelf()
                .OfType<JObject>()
                .Select(parent => parent[c])
                .Where(v => v is JValue)
                .Select(v => (string)v)
                .FirstOrDefault())
                .Reverse() // Trim trailing nulls
                .SkipWhile(s => s == null)
                .Reverse());

        // Convert to CSV
        var csvRows = new[] { columns }.Concat(rows).Select(r => string.Join(",", r));
        var csv = string.Join("\n", csvRows);

        Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

Using

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471899/how-to-convert-linq-results-to-hashset-or-hashedset
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> F1,F2,E1,E2,D1,D2
> 1,2
> 1,2,3,4
> 1,2,5,6
> 1,2,7,8,9,10
> ```

Comment: It is a shame this has not been marked as a solution or at least commented on.  Something....  If I end up giving this a try I'll report back.

Comment: brilliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this and it is working for me
Here we save all breadcrumps of object tree in headers with format prop_prop
And save jarray property objects in headers in format prop1

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> ComplexJsonToDictionary(JObject jObject, Dictionary<string, string> result, string field)
    {
        foreach (var property in jObject.Properties())
        {
            var endField = field + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field) ? "" : "_") + property.Name;

            var innerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                var innerValue = JObject.Parse(Convert.ToString(property.Value));


                result.AddOrOverride(ComplexJsonToDictionary(innerValue, innerDictionary, endField));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    var innerValues = JArray.Parse(Convert.ToString(property.Value));
                    try
                    {
                        var i = 0;
                        foreach (var token in innerValues)
                        {
                            var innerValue = JObject.Parse(Convert.ToString(token));

                            result.AddOrOverride(ComplexJsonToDictionary(innerValue, innerDictionary, endField+i++));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        result.Add(endField, string.Join(",", innerValues.Values<string>()));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    result.Add(endField, property.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks for atantion and please write review if appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

pass the json parsed jobject to static extension, then it will return the array of jobjects with flatten, then convert to csv. some of the source code is taken from the other stack overflow and other resources, I don't have reference.

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> JsonToCsvRowsWithHierarchyHeaders(string jsonData)
    {
        if (jsonData.Trim().StartsWith("[") && jsonData.Trim().EndsWith("]"))
        {
            var startString = "{\"appendRoot\":";
            var endString = "}";
            jsonData = $"{startString}{jsonData}{endString}";
        }

        var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonData);
        var flattenJObjects = JsonParserExtensions.FlattenJsonGetJObjects(jObject).ToList();
  
        var csvRows = new List<string>();
        if (flattenJObjects.Any())
        {
            var firstRow = flattenJObjects.First().Children<JProperty>().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            var header = string.Join(delimeter, firstRow).Replace("appendRoot_", "").ToLower();
            csvRows.Add(header);
            foreach (var flattenJObject in flattenJObjects)
            {
                var tokens = flattenJObject.Children<JProperty>();

                if (firstRow.Count() != tokens.Count())
                {
                    var missMatchPropertyValues = firstRow.Select(cell => tokens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == cell))
                        .Select(value => value == null
                            ? string.Empty
                            : CheckAndUpdateRowCellValueTextQualifier(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(value.Value.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None))))
                        .ToList();
                    var rowString = string.Join(delimeter, missMatchPropertyValues);
                    csvRows.Add(rowString);
                }
                else
                {
                    var rowValue = tokens.Select(token =>
                        CheckAndUpdateRowCellValueTextQualifier(
                            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(
                                token.Value.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None))));
                    var rowString = string.Join(delimeter, rowValue);
                    csvRows.Add(rowString);
                }
            }
        }
        return csvRows;
    }

 
    private static string CheckAndUpdateRowCellValueTextQualifier(string value)
    {
        const string q = @"""";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Contains('\"'))
        {
            return value;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && (value.Contains(',') ||
                                         value.Contains('"') ||
                                         value.Contains('\n') || value.Contains('\r')))
        {
            return $"{q}{value}{q}";
        }
        
        return value;
    }
}

public static class JsonParserExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JObject> FlattenJsonGetJObjects(JObject jObject, string parentName = null)
    {
        if (!(parentName is null))
            jObject = RenamePropertiesByHierarchyName(jObject, parentName);

        var fields = jObject.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.GetType().Name == "JValue").ToList();
        var objects = jObject.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.GetType().Name == "JObject").ToList();
        var arrays = jObject.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.GetType().Name == "JArray").ToList();
        var objectsArray = arrays.Where(array => array.Value.All(elements => elements.GetType().Name == "JObject")).ToList();
        var valuesArray = arrays.Where(array => array.Value.All(elements => elements.GetType().Name == "JValue")).ToList();

        var nestedObjects = ProcessNestedObjects(objects);

        var joinedInnerObjects = nestedObjects.Any()
            ? nestedObjects.Select(innerObject => JoinJObject(new JObject(fields), innerObject))
            : new List<JObject> { new JObject(fields) };

        var arraysObjectList = GetJObjectsFromArrayOfJProperties(objectsArray);
        var arraysValueList = GetJObjectsFromArrayOfValues(valuesArray);
        var joinedAll = joinedInnerObjects.SelectMany(inner => JoinMultipleJObjects(arraysObjectList, arraysValueList, inner));
        return joinedAll;
    }

    public static List<JObject> ProcessNestedObjects(List<JProperty> jObjects)
    {
        var processNestedObjects = new List<JObject>();
        var renamedJObjects = jObjects?.Select(obj => RenamePropertiesByHierarchyName(obj.Value.ToObject<JObject>(), obj.Name)).ToList();

        if (!(renamedJObjects?.Count > 0)) return processNestedObjects;
        var renamed = renamedJObjects.Aggregate((acc, next) => JoinJObject(acc, next));

        var nestedObjects = renamed.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.GetType().Name == "JObject").ToList();
        var nestedArrays = renamed.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.GetType().Name == "JArray").ToList();
        var nestedObjectsArray = nestedArrays.Where(array => array.Value.All(elements => elements.GetType().Name == "JObject")).ToList();
        var nestedValuesArray = nestedArrays.Where(array => array.Value.All(elements => elements.GetType().Name == "JValue")).ToList();

        nestedArrays.ForEach(p => renamed.Remove(p.Name));
        nestedObjects.ForEach(p => renamed.Remove(p.Name));

        var nestedObjectList = new List<JObject>();
        var nestedMultipleObjectList = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (var listJObjects in nestedObjects.Select(innerObject => FlattenJsonGetJObjects(innerObject.Value.ToObject<JObject>(), innerObject.Name)).ToList())
        {
            if (listJObjects.Count() > 1)
                nestedMultipleObjectList.AddRange(listJObjects);
            else
                nestedObjectList.Add(listJObjects.First());
        }

        var jObjectsFromArrayOfJProperties = GetJObjectsFromArrayOfJProperties(nestedObjectsArray);
        var jObjectsFromArrayOfValues = GetJObjectsFromArrayOfValues(nestedValuesArray);

        var aggregate = nestedObjectList.Aggregate(renamed, (acc, next) => JoinJObject(acc, next));
        var groupedNestedObjects = (nestedMultipleObjectList.Any()) ? nestedMultipleObjectList.Select(nested => JoinJObject(aggregate, nested))
            : new List<JObject> { aggregate };
        var groupedNestedObjectsList = groupedNestedObjects.Select(groupedNested => JoinMultipleJObjects(jObjectsFromArrayOfJProperties, jObjectsFromArrayOfValues, groupedNested));
        processNestedObjects.AddRange(groupedNestedObjectsList.SelectMany(e => e));
        return processNestedObjects;
    }

    public static List<JObject> JoinMultipleJObjects(List<JObject> nestedArraysObjectList, List<JObject> nestedArraysValueList, JObject groupedNestedObjects)
    {
        var result = new List<JObject>();
        var joined = new List<JObject>();
        if (!nestedArraysObjectList.Any())
            joined.Add(groupedNestedObjects);
        else
            nestedArraysObjectList.ForEach(e => joined.Add(JoinJObject(groupedNestedObjects, e)));

        result.AddRange(nestedArraysValueList.Any()
            ? nestedArraysValueList
                .SelectMany(value => joined, (value, joinedItem) => JoinJObject(joinedItem, value)).ToList()
            : joined);
        return result;
    }

    public static List<JObject> GetJObjectsFromArrayOfJProperties(List<JProperty> nestedJProperties)
    {
        var fromArrayOfJProperties = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (var jProperty in nestedJProperties)
        {
            var nestedArraysObjectList = new List<JObject>();
            var name = jProperty.Name;
            var jPropertyValue = jProperty.Value;
            var renamedObjects = jPropertyValue?.Select(obj => RenamePropertiesByHierarchyName(obj.ToObject<JObject>(), name)).ToList();
            foreach (var jObjects in renamedObjects.Select(innerObject => FlattenJsonGetJObjects(innerObject.ToObject<JObject>())))
            {
                nestedArraysObjectList.AddRange(jObjects);
            }

            if (fromArrayOfJProperties.Any() && nestedArraysObjectList.Any())
                fromArrayOfJProperties = nestedArraysObjectList
                    .SelectMany(nested => fromArrayOfJProperties, (current, joined) => JoinJObject(joined, current)).ToList();

            if (!fromArrayOfJProperties.Any())
                fromArrayOfJProperties.AddRange(nestedArraysObjectList);
        }
        return fromArrayOfJProperties;
    }

    public static List<JObject> GetJObjectsFromArrayOfValues(List<JProperty> nestedValuesArray)
    {
        return (from innerArray in nestedValuesArray let name = innerArray.Name let values = innerArray.Value from innerValue in values select new JObject(new JProperty(name, innerValue.ToObject<JValue>()))).ToList();
    }

    public static JObject RenamePropertiesByHierarchyName(JObject jObject, string hierarchyName)
    {
        var properties = jObject.Properties().ToList().Select(p => new JProperty($"{hierarchyName}_{p.Name}", p.Value));
        return new JObject(properties);
    }

    public static JObject JoinJObject(JObject parentJObject, JObject innerObject)
    {
        var joinJObject = new JObject
            {
                parentJObject.Properties(),
                innerObject.Properties()
            };
        return joinJObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31027121)