# C # .Net code to convert dynamic nested Json obj to CSV using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#

I need to  write a C# Program to convert dynamic complex nested json file to CSV. I cant use ChoETL or CSVHelper libraries only can use NewtonSoft .Json .

I have tried to convert the json object into flatenned object

```
var fobj=JObject.Parse(jsonobj).
          Descendents().OFType<JValue>().
          ToDictionary(jv=>jv.Path ,jv=>jv.ToString());
```

But writing the fobj dictionary to CSV will not give the expected output.

Is there anyway we can convert nested dynamic json to CSV ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert nested JSON to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961051/convert-nested-json-to-csv)

Comment: no , it doesn't . Is there any other way ?

Comment: Do you have an example of one of your json files and what is your expected output? Without knowing this its hard to help you