# LINQ query for finding one item in list AND verifying list does not contain another item

Tags: c#, linq

So far I have come up with this:

```
list.Any(s => s.EnumIdValue == Close) && !list.Any(s => s.EnumIdValue == Reset || s.EnumIdValue == Cancel);
```

EnumIdValue contains several different possible values like Close, Reset, Cancel, SomeOtherState, etc. There should never be duplicates but it's still possible.

This does exactly what I want. But would there be a better (shorter) way to write this query?

Comment: There should be some badge for writing a question that seems so easy and gets multiple guess answers that are all incorrect.

Comment: CoderDennis: It wasn't my intention but you're right I guess I should. :P

Comment: The answers are incorrect because the question is misleading. In fact, I don't even see a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: *There is no better way to write it.*

If you try to write it in one lambda, you can think of the `s` as a single item in the list. If the item is a `Close`, it will of course not be something else so it's useless to check for that in the same lambda. If you want to check if the list doesn't contain some other values, you're forced to do it with another expression.

Answer (score 4):

Your original is fine. The other variant that would work is this:

```
var newQuery =
    list.Any(s => s.EnumIdValue == EnumIdValue.Close) &&
    list.All(s => s.EnumIdValue != EnumIdValue.Reset &&
                  s.EnumIdValue != EnumIdValue.Cancel);
```

In English: does the list have at least one `Close` *and* is every item in the list not `Reset` and not `Cancel`?

By the way, sometimes formatting your code nicely makes a big difference in terms of readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471927/3140) to test if the collection contains *at least 1* of each `EnumIdValue`:

```
var enumIds = list.Select(s => s.EnumIdValue).ToHashSet();

return enumIds.Contains(Close) && !(enumIds.Contains(Cancel) || enumIds.Contains(Reset));

// or

return enumIds
  .Intersect(new[] { Cancel, Reset, Close })
  .SequenceEqual(new [] { Close });

// or (throws exception)

enumIds.IntersectWith(new[] { Cancel, Reset, Close })
return enumIds.Single() == Close;
```

This would be useful if you need to do different types of checks based on whether or not `enumIds` contains `Close`.

Comment: `IntersectsWith` or just `Intersect`?

Comment: @devuxer: let's stick with `IntersectWith` for now. I did have the return value wrong.

Comment: I ask because `IntersectWith` (or `IntersectsWith`) does not exist in native LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx

Comment: On never mind. I see it's an actual method of `HashSet`.

Comment: It does seem like converting to `HasSet` is unnecessary in this case, though--you could just leave it as an `IEnumerable` and use `Intersect`. You might be able to make a case for performance, but I'd argue that's premature optimization, and I wouldn't automatically assume that `ToHashSet` saves time (depends on the internal implementation of `Intersect`). Interesting answer, nonetheless :)

Comment: @devuxer: Yes, and `.Single()` throws an exception when `.Count() != 1`. I posted another example using `Intersect` and `SequenceEqual`. That gives me an idea for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    var items = list.Select(s => s.EnumIdValue == Close) 
    if(items.Count==1)
    {
       //todo
    }
```

Comment: That only addresses half the question and not even very well

Comment: What if it contains 3 copies of Close?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly readable alternative:

```
var opts = new [] { Close, Reset, Cancel };
var desired = new [] { Close };
return list
        .Select(s => s.EnumIdValue)
        .Distinct()
        .Where(opts.Contains)
        .SequenceEqual(desired);
```