# Iterate on union of several dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

I have five dictionaries of type `Dictionary<ThingId, Thing>` and `Dictionary<ThingId, List<Thing>>`. I want to iterate on all of them with the following rules:

1. Iterate on all the ThingId without duplicate
2. For each key (aka each Id), get the list of Thing from all dictionaries **without mixing them** (they do not have the same functional meaning).

For now, I do this:

```
void DoSomething(Dictionary<ThingId, Thing> dic1, Dictionary<ThingId, List<Thing>> dic2, Dictionary<ThingId, List<Thing>> dic3) // only 3 to not clutter the code
{
    var ids = new HashSet<ThingId>(dic1.Keys).AddRange(dic2.Keys).AddRange(dic3.Keys);

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        Thing thing1;
        List<Thing> things2;
        List<Thing> things3;

        if (!dic1.TryGetValue(id, out thing1)
        {
            //default
            thing1 = new Thing(id);
        }
        if (!dic2.TryGetValue(id, out things2)
        {
            //default
            things2 = new List<Thing>();
        }
        if (!dic3.TryGetValue(id, out things3)
        {
            //default
            things3 = new List<Thing>();
        }
        DoSomethingElse(thing1, things2, things3);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this with `Linq`? For example do an union of the keys of the dictionaries and build anonymous class from the values (with the "default" values when needed)?

I looked at the `Union` method, but it does not what I want.

Comment: i dont know much about linq union but maybe you could use AsParalell() to improve itteration performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is pretty inefficient performance-wise, but with Linq:

```
    void DoSomething(Dictionary<ThingId, Thing> dic1, Dictionary<ThingId, List<Thing>> dic2, Dictionary<ThingId, List<Thing>> dic3) // only 3 to not clutter the code
    {
         dic1.Keys.Union(dic2.Keys).Union(dic3.Keys).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(id =>
            DoSomethingElse(
                dic1.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == id).Value ?? new Thing(id),
                dic2.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == id).Value ?? new List<Thing>(),
                dic3.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == id).Value ?? new List<Thing>())
        );
    }
```

Another way would be to extend your Dictionary and then use that extension:

```
    public static class DictionaryExtension
    {
        public static VType GetSafeValue<KType, VType>(this Dictionary<KType, VType> dic, KType key) where VType : class
        {
            VType v;
            if (!dic.TryGetValue(key, out v))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

then you may use

```
dic1.Keys.Union(dic2.Keys).Union(dic3.Keys).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(id =>
            DoSomethingElse(
                dic1.GetSafeValue(id) ?? new Thing(id),
                dic2.GetSafeValue(id) ?? new List<Thing>(),
                dic3.GetSafeValue(id) ?? new List<Thing>())
        );
```

Comment: That is basically the same algorithm, but with Linq, is not it?

Comment: A kind of. I believe that it is much worse, because it does not access dictionary values with indexer, but uses FirstOrDefault instead. I did not really tested it, but I doubt Linq could optimize this properly, so instead of a fast indexer access we slowly iterate over the dictionary matching keys one by one. But yes, it is with Linq :)

Comment: At least, it is more readable. I made a research and it is also possible to create a `HashSet` from an `IEnumerable`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471899/how-to-convert-linq-results-to-hashset-or-hashedset

Comment: Honestly, I do not see how HashSet could help here.

Comment: Maybe `HashSet.FirstOrDefault` is better optimized than the `List` equivalent.

Comment: Maybe, but IMO converting into HashSet would introduce even higher overhead. I have a kind of idea how to solve the performance issue, I'll extend my answer with it now.