# Combining information from multiple lists

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq, sorting

I have multiple `string[]` that are defined like this:

```
var allEntities = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" }
var entitiesWithPriority = new[] { "c", "d", "g" }
var entitiesWithIssue = new [] { "d", "h", "i" }
var entitiesWith... = new [] { ... }
```

Now I'd like to compile a single list from those arrays by using the following class structure:

```
class Entity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasPriority { get; set; }
    public bool HasIssue { get; set; }
}
```

The result of the operation should therefore be something like this:

```
[
    { "name": "a", "hasPriority": false, "hasIssue": false }
    { "name": "b", "hasPriority": false, "hasIssue": false }
    { "name": "c", "hasPriority": true, "hasIssue": false }
    { "name": "d", "hasPriority": true, "hasIssue": true }
    { "name": "e", "hasPriority": false, "hasIssue": false }
    { "name": "f", "hasPriority": false, "hasIssue": false }
    { "name": "g", "hasPriority": true, "hasIssue": false }
    { "name": "h", "hasPriority": false, "hasIssue": true }
    { "name": "i", "hasPriority": false, "hasIssue": true }
]
```

I could do something in the lines of the following code, but I think this solution is not perfect at all:

```
var result = allEntities.Select(entityName => new Entity()
{
    Name = entityName,
    HasPriority = entitiesWithPriority.Contains(entityName),
    HasIssue = entitiesWithIssue.Contains(entityName)
});
```

How can I compile such a list while being performance efficient.

Comment: "huge performance issues"? How many million entities are you going to end up with?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I will probably end up with about 10.000 to 100.000 entries. The problem is, that every `Contains` or `Any` call would go through the whole list, so I am looking for a good solution. The problem described above is just a simplified example by the way. The problem will probably not be the amount of entries but the number of calls. I generate about 10 to 50 of those array combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `dictionary <string>,<entity>` and populate it from all entities with all hasXXX defaults to false

After that, lookup is O(1)

```
foreach (var key in EntitiesWithPriority)
{
   dict[key].hasPriority = true
}
```

and so on

Comment: This seems like a sleek approach. Still feel like there might be a solution that is solely based on `for loops`, that might be quicker.

Comment: well - perhaps a better solution is to investigate the code where you are building all your EntitiesWith.... after all, while you are creating these arrays you might already fill the dictionary...

Comment: Sadly there seems no easy way around it. I already investigated it. I am working with expressions to get those lists at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary` or a `Hashset` to reduce `Any` and `Contains` complexity from `O(n)` to `O(1)`:

The idea above can still be used for *large* lists to replace list/array/IEnumarable<> `Contains` which is `O(n)` with `Hashset`'s Contains which is `O(1)`.

```
var entitiesWithPriorityMap = entitiesWithPriority.ToDictionary(e => e.entityName, e => true);  
var entitiesWithIssueMap = entitiesWithIssue.ToDictionary(e => e.entityName, e => true);

var result = allEntities.Select(entityName => new Entity()
{
    Name = entityName,
    HasPriority = entitiesWithPriorityMap.ContainsKey(entityName),
    HasIssue = entitiesWithIssueMap.ContainsKey(entityName)
});
```

Note: This works when dealing with Linq2Object nor Linq2Sql (cannot generate SQL out of `Contains` in this scenario).

**`Hashset` version**

```
var entitiesWithPriorityMap = new HashSet<Entity>(entitiesWithPriority);
var entitiesWithIssueMap = new HashSet<Entity>(entitiesWithIssue);

// replace ContainsKey with Contains
```

Comment: I have updated the question, because I think you might have misunderstood what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @SebastianKrogull - yes, I got it now. However, the idea still holds as you need to make lookups much faster, since they execute for each `Select` step. Normally, a `Hashset` is enough, but there is no `Linq` extension to obtain a Hashset directly.

Comment: Just a small additional information: Items in the arrays can just contain items from the AllEntities array.

Comment: Why dictionary if HashSet will do?

Comment: @Evk - I have used the Dictionary because there is already a built-in extension method to obtain it. However, a `Hashset` can be easily obtained using the extension method provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471927/2780791).

Comment: Well, you can just do `new HashSet(entitiesWithPriority)`, no need for any extensions.

Comment: @Evk - yes. I have already added this info for the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could join them together:

```
var entities = 
     from name in allEntities
     join pr in entitiesWithPriority on name equals pr into np
     from priority in np.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join iss in entitiesWithIssue on name equals iss into npi
     from issue in npi.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new Entity 
     { 
         Name = name, 
         HasPriority = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(priority), 
         HasIssue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(issue)
     };
```

Comment: While this is clearly the cleanest way to achieve OPs goal, the "LEFT JOIN"s would still perform match in O(n), which might not be fast enough for *large* lists.

Answer (score 0):

If the construction can be `List<>` instead from an `array`, we can create a `List<>` with the following generic type: `List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>`
To achieve such construction you need to create following method:

```
public List<List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>> MethodName()
    {
        var list = new List<List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>>();

        HasPriority = false;
        HasIssue = false;

        foreach (var item in allEntities)
        {
            if (entitiesWithPriority.Contains(item.ToString()))
                HasPriority = true;
            if (entitiesWithIssue.Contains(item.ToString()))
                HasIssue = true;
            list.Add(new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>()
            {
                (new Dictionary<string, dynamic>() { { "name", item } }),
                (new Dictionary<string, dynamic>() { { "hasPriority", HasPriority } }),
                (new Dictionary<string, dynamic>() { { "hasIssue", HasIssue } })
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I'm not sure if all properties in your class are necessary. In case you'd want to add more arrays with conditions you should modify foreach loop.