# C# Linq Union Collections in nested query

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to express this snippet in Linq but I cannot wrap my mind around it. `_gameTableEntries` is basically a tuple with fields `long tableId` and `ICollection<object> connectedClients`

```
private ICollection<GameTableEntry> _gameTableEntries = new (...);

public ICollection<ConnectionHandler> GetConnectedClients(long tableId)
{
    HashSet<ConnectionHandler> set = new HashSet<ConnectionHandler>();

    foreach (var tableEntry in _gameTableEntries)
    {
        if (!tableEntry.TableId.Equals(tableId)) continue;

        foreach (var handler in tableEntry.ConnectedClients)
        {
            if (!handler.IsConnected) continue;

            set.Add(handler);
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

Comment: `_gameTableEntries.Where(x => !x.TableId.Equals(tableId)).Select(x => x.ConnectedClients).Where(x => x.IsConnected).ToList()`. it will return a list instead of `HashSet`, you can add [ToHashSet Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471927/4648586) though.

Comment: @BagusTesa `ICollection<Connectionhandler> does not contain a definition for IsConnected`

Comment: @Benj thats why you need `SelectMany`

Comment: ah my bad, i forgot that `ConnectedClients` is `IEnumerable` themself, so need to use `SelectMany`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are possibly after something like this with [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
public ICollection<ConnectionHandler> GetConnectedClients(long tableId)
  => _gameTableEntries.Where(x => x.TableId == tableId)
                      .SelectMany(x => x.ConnectedClients)
                      .Where(x => x.IsConnected)
                      .ToHashSet();
```

Comment: The problem is that the IsConnected is a property of ConnectionHandler.

Comment: @Benj thats why we are using SelectMany, we are selecting the many ConnectionHandler. however let me know if the above doesnt work

Comment: this expression looks correct.. the only concern I would have here is thread-safety considerations because of this `ConnectionHandler` type, but that probably isn't in the scope of this Q&A

Comment: @BrettCaswell yeah i know what you mean, which would be a concern anyway really

Comment: @BrettCaswell it is is single threaded async websocket application