# Linq query in single threaded process throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq, exception, .net-core

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496523/c-sharp-linq-union-collections-in-nested-query/58496549#58496549) I asked for help to change a snippet to Linq. Today this query threw an unexpected `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message **Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated** which surprises me because the application runs single threaded.

## Screenshot

[image: Exception Screenshot]

## System Architecture Overview

The application accepts connections using the `System.Net` and `System.Net.Websockets` namespaces. Messages are received, processed and sent using `async` and `await`. Timeout features are implemented using `System.Timers.Timer`.

Websocket connections are managed by so called `ConnectionHandler` which are managed in a singleton module `TableManager` which maintains a hashset of elements that (among others) exposes a `List<ConnectionHandler>` on which this query is run.

## Exception details

### Message

**Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.**

### Stacktrace

```
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n

-- (snip) ------------------------------------------------------------

at (snip).TableManager.GetConnectedClients(Int64 tableId)
at (snip).WebsocketProtocolFeatureImpl`1.OnPlayerFolds(Object sender, PlayerDidFoldEventArgs`1 e) 
at (snip).PokerHand`1._Handle_BettingRound_PlayerDidFold(Object sender, PlayerDidFoldEventArgs`1 e) 
at (snip).BettingRound`1._OnPlayerDidFold(Participant`1 p) 
at (snip).BettingRound`1.Fold() 
at (snip).PokerHand`1.CheckOrFold(T_PlayerId player) 
at (snip).PokerHand`1.CheckOrFold() 
at (snip).WebsocketProtocolFeatureImpl`1.<.ctor>b__12_1(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 

-- (snip) ------------------------------------------------------------

at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
```

### Internal Iterator

```
|----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Name                       | Value                                                                                                                                    |
|----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| TargetSite                 | {Boolean MoveNext()}                                                                                                                     |
| Attributes                 | Public, Final, Virtual, HideBySig, NewSlot                                                                                               |
| CallingConvention          | Standard, HasThis                                                                                                                        |
| ContainsGenericParameters  | TRUE                                                                                                                                     |
| CustomAttributes           | Method System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.                                               |
| DeclaringType              | {Name = "Enumerator" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1+Enumerator"}                                                       |
| IsAbstract                 | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsAssembly                 | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsCollectible              | Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsCollectible cannot be called in this context.                                           |
| IsConstructedGenericMethod | Method System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_IsConstructedGenericMethod cannot be called in this context.                                     |
| IsConstructor              | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsFamily                   | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsFamilyAndAssembly        | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsFamilyOrAssembly         | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsFinal                    | TRUE                                                                                                                                     |
| IsGenericMethod            | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsGenericMethodDefinition  | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsHideBySig                | TRUE                                                                                                                                     |
| IsPrivate                  | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsPublic                   | TRUE                                                                                                                                     |
| IsSecurityCritical         | Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityCritical cannot be called in this context.                                      |
| IsSecuritySafeCritical     | Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecuritySafeCritical cannot be called in this context.                                  |
| IsSecurityTransparent      | Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityTransparent cannot be called in this context.                                   |
| IsSpecialName              | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsStatic                   | FALSE                                                                                                                                    |
| IsVirtual                  | TRUE                                                                                                                                     |
| MemberType                 | Method                                                                                                                                   |
| MetadataToken              | 100663466                                                                                                                                |
| MethodHandle               | {System.RuntimeMethodHandle}                                                                                                             |
| MethodImplementationFlags  | Method System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_MethodImplementationFlags cannot be called in this context.                                      |
| Module                     | {System.Collections.dll}                                                                                                                 |
| Name                       | "MoveNext"                                                                                                                               |
| ReflectedType              | '((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)($exception).TargetSite).ReflectedType' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' |
| ReturnParameter            | {System.Boolean }                                                                                                                        |
| ReturnType                 | {Name = "Boolean" FullName = "System.Boolean"}                                                                                           |
| ReturnTypeCustomAttributes | Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnTypeCustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.                              |
| Non-Public members         |                                                                                                                                          |
|----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Who put the data in _gameTableEntries? If it is an incoming websocket connection then that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @shan Correct, a ConnectionHandler registers itself during an onConnect event. however I don't understand how that could possibly happen during the LINQ since they are sync calls. The thread is busy so how can it possibly accept a connection?

Comment: The [`WebSocketBase`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketBase.cs,1023d8c3949a872d) class uses `Task` internally, which may or may not run on a separate thread.

Comment: Websocket is by nature asynchronous. You should acquire a lock on _gameTableEntries before writing on it.

Comment: @BurnsBA So I need to keep thread safety in mind when developing applications that use `async`? So far I thought using `async` brings the advantage of not having to worry about that because there is only one active thread.

Comment: @ShanNautiyal So you can use locks in `async` calls, just not `await` inside a lock?