# ToHashSet IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, list

I am getting this error not sure why I tried both version using the Template object and just list of string. is there something else I need to do?

```
HashSet<Template> selectedPatientsHashSet = templates.Select(p => p.VersionKey).ToHashSet<Template>();

var selectedPatientsHashSet = templates.Select(p => p.VersionKey).ToHashSet();
```

[image: Object type]

[image: VersionKey type]

[[image: Runtime Error1]

Comment: Are you using System.Linq & are you using .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: I am not using .net core I was thinking it was just apart of linq

Comment: That method wasn't introduced until .Net Core 3.1 I think (maybe 3.0). 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471899/how-to-convert-linq-results-to-hashset-or-hashedset

^here is an extension method someone on stackoverflow came up with to give it to older frameworks :)

Comment: Do both lines of code fail? The 1st is obviously wrong since `Select()` returns an `IQueryable<string>` not `IQueryable<Template>`

Comment: Yes both have runtime errors

Comment: [ToHashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.8) is available in .net core starting 2.0 and full .net framework starting 4.7.2. I'd suggest you check your current SDK/Runtime versions

Comment: Why is ToHashSet not available in .NET Standard 2.0, when it's available in .NET 4.7.2 and .NET Core 2.0? Makes no sense. I'm just setting here porting some code from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET Standard 2.0 and it's complaining there's no ToHashSet extension method on the Enumerable class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same exact issue. Why the .NET team failed to include the `.ToHashSet()` extension method in Standard 2.0 is beyond me, as I am also trying to work towards moving some code from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET. I know the extension method is in .NET Standard 2.1 but that is incompatible with .NET Framework 4.8...this has been a headache to be sure!

My solution was to create my own extension method in my root namespace. Not as "clean" as having the method already available in Linq, but it gets the job done with minimal invasiveness:

```cs
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
   return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
}
```